# I am writing an If then else to check for specific numeric value in a file

Tags: shell-script

I am writing an If then else script to check if a certain value exists in a file. If the value exists, print value exists, else print value does not exist.

```
#!/bin/bash
#This script will check a file and determine if the QID exists.
#search the zero day file for qids and system tracking id's. These are contained in
#the file file.

echo What is the QID number $HOME?
read QID

#Set some variables
Qualyfile=$(cat /home/dc368/zeroday/zerodayresearch)
QualysID=$QID

If [ $Qualyfile|grep $QualysID = $QualysID ]; then 
    echo qid exists
else echo qid does not exist
fi
```

Comment: Hey ItGuru1, what is the question?  Let us know, then we can help you.

Comment: Paste your code into http://shellcheck.net for bash syntax errors

Comment: My script keeps failing at this line: "If [ $Qualyfile|grep $QualysID = $QualysID ]; then ".
Not sure what I need to do to fix. All I am trying to do is search a file for a certain number. If that number is there, print some message. If that number is not there, print some other message.

Here is the error in debug mode:
-------------------------------

./zero.research: line 14: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
./zero.research: line 14: `If [ $Qualyfile|grep $QualysID = $QualysID ]; then '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that, after `if`, you put a **command**. Depending on the *exit status* of that command, you enter the `then` block or the `else` block. Also note that `[` is a **command**, not just syntax (at a bash prompt, type `help [` then `help test`)

You want

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "What is the QID? " qid
file=/home/dc368/zeroday/zerodayresearch
if grep -q "$qid" "$file"; then
    echo qid exists
else 
    echo qid does not exist
fi
```

Since grep uses regular expressions, this may return false positives. For example, if `qid=.`, grep returns "true" if there is at least one character in the file. Read `man grep` for the extensive options to help narrow your results (hint, consider the `-w` and `-F` options.

Note also that I have avoided using ALLCAPS variable names. [They can cause problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28310594/ls-not-found-after-running-read-path) if you're not careful. Best practice is to avoid using them.

Comment: @ITguru1, you should read https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers